# Mockito: how to verify method was called inside another method, which always throws Exception?

Tags: junit, exception, mockito

I am testing a method with an expected exception. 
I also need to verify that some code was called (on a mocked object) after the exception is thrown, but verification is being ignored. 
Here is the code:

```
public class ExceptionHandler {

    @Autowired
    private Sender sender;

    public void handle(Exception exception) throws Exception {
      if (!SomeException.class.isAssignableFrom(exception.getClass())) {
        sender.sendMessage(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(exception));
      }
      throw exception;
    }
}
```

Here is the test code:

```
@Mock
private Sender sender;

@InjectMocks
private ExceptionHandler handler;

@Test
public void testHandler() throws Exception {
    SomeException someException = new SomeException();

    try {
        handler.handle(someException);
    } catch (SomeException thrownResult) {
        assertEquals(someException, thrownResult);
    }

    verify(sender, times(1)).sendMessage(Mockito.anyString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also need to verify that some code was called (on a mocked object)
> after the exception is thrown, but verification is being ignored.

This is not true, this line *is* actually executed:

```
verify(sender, times(1)).sendMessage(Mockito.anyString());
```

But it fails verification with this error:

> Wanted but not invoked: sender.sendMessage();
>
> <...>
>
> Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

As expected, that method was never invoked, because condition `!SomeException.class.isAssignableFrom(exception.getClass())` was not satisfied - you invoke `handler.handle` with instance of `SomeException`.